# IDE Can not ReInstall Android App on next launch

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea

There is ASUS Tablet fonpad 7" , Android v.5 (Updated From **KitKat**)
IDE **IntelliJ Idea** v.14 And **Android Studio**
Every time i try to Run App on device it take a moment and abort installing and i have to uninstall App **manually**.

It means, First Time Launch App From Android Studio it launch well, but at next time launch it again "First time launched App" Relaunch and I See no change On "Next time launches" until "uninstall " App

when i try on other devices, App Runs Well !
works on Samsung Tablet And Mobiles, LG G3 LG G2 ...

> also it shows in Run Area:

```
    Target device: asus-k019-EAOKBC586456
    Uploading file
        local path: C:\wamp\www\Bidbarg\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk
        remote path: /data/local/tmp/com.hosseinkurd.app.bidbarg
    Installing com.hosseinkurd.app.bidbarg
    DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.hosseinkurd.app.bidbarg"
    pkg: /data/local/tmp/com.hosseinkurd.app.bidbarg
    Success


    Launching application: com.hosseinkurd.app.bidbarg/com.hosseinkurd.app.bidbarg.activities.SplashActivity.
    DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: am start -n "com.hosseinkurd.app.bidbarg/com.hosseinkurd.app.bidbarg.activities.SplashActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
    java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for java.lang.String android.os.SystemProperties.native_get(java.lang.String, java.lang.String) (tried Java_android_os_SystemProperties_native_1get and Java_android_os_SystemProperties_native_1get__Ljava_lang_String_2Ljava_lang_String_2)
    at android.os.SystemProperties.native_get(Native Method)
    at android.os.SystemProperties.get(SystemProperties.java:64)
    at android.os.Environment.<clinit>(Environment.java:918)
    at android.os.Environment.getLegacyExternalStorageDirectory(Environment.java:419)
    at android.os.Debug.<clinit>(Debug.java:96)
    at android.ddm.DdmHandleHello.handleHELO(DdmHandleHello.java:164)
    at android.ddm.DdmHandleHello.handleChunk(DdmHandleHello.java:91)
    at org.apache.harmony.dalvik.ddmc.DdmServer.dispatch(DdmServer.java:171)
    java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: android.os.Debug
    at android.ddm.DdmHandleHello.handleFEAT(DdmHandleHello.java:176)
    at android.ddm.DdmHandleHello.handleChunk(DdmHandleHello.java:93)
    at org.apache.harmony.dalvik.ddmc.DdmServer.dispatch(DdmServer.java:171)
    java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: android.os.Debug
    at android.ddm.DdmHandleProfiling.handleMPRQ(DdmHandleProfiling.java:187)
    at android.ddm.DdmHandleProfiling.handleChunk(DdmHandleProfiling.java:88)
    at org.apache.harmony.dalvik.ddmc.DdmServer.dispatch(DdmServer.java:171)
    Aborted
```

How To Solve It ?

Comment: Does the console throw any error?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what exactly will help you, but try next solutions:

- switch off the "Verify Apps over USB" in the "Developer Options"
- install another launcher
- disable ADB integration in Android Studio (Tools > Android > uncheck Enable ADB integration). But you will be unable to debug app in this case.

Comment: It doesn't works to me! is there another way to fix it ?